What kind or brand of cartridge is this?
I’m trying to understand how I can change the cartridge myself. So far I’ve done the same work once and that was a Moen cartridge. But this one(in attached photo) is difficult to take it off, and I can’t tell what brand it is.



Might help to post a picture of the knobs and so forth. Kind of hard to tell from this limited view.

Based on the two holes at the bottom to anchor the escutcheon plate, I believe that is a very old Moen.
Moen trim
